# PHP page counter script

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php, obviously.. 
I have created a simple page counter for a webpage to monitor the number of views.
I've set up a mySQL database with three columns (id, page, views).
and have included the following script on the relative pages, 
HOWEVER.. instead of increasing the count by 1, it increases it by 2 every time and I have no idea why.  Can anyone help?

```
   <?php
    $page= 'index';

    include('solrx_scripts.php');

    $sql="SELECT * FROM view_log WHERE page = 'index'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $previous = $row['views'];
    }
    $new_count = $previous + 1;

    mysql_query("UPDATE view_log SET views=$new_count WHERE id = 'index'");

    exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: Where is the "following script"?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: How about you just create a function?

Comment: You know you could just run an update query: "UPDATE view_log SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = 'index'"

Comment: Other than the whole mysql thing, you should enclose variables in quotes in queries, so use: `UPDATE view_log SET views='$new_count' WHERE id = 'index'`. You also want to make sure that this script is only run once. It's also not necessary to use a while loop, just use `$row = mysql_fetch_row($result)` and `$previous = $row['views'];`

Answer (score 3):

Try doing the addition in SQL instead of PHP

`mysql_query("UPDATE view_log SET views=views+1 WHERE id = 'index'");`

Bear in mind that search engine spiders will cause the view count to be updated also. Something like Google Analytics will give you far more reliable statistics.

Answer (score 1):

You just need one line for this :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `view_log` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `id` = 'index'");
```

and please **DON'T** use mysql php functions, you will definetly have many problems in the future as it is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Make it simply like this no need to select if You always want just add 1

```
$page= 'index';

include('solrx_scripts.php');

mysql_query("UPDATE view_log SET views=views+1 WHERE id = 'index'");

exit;
```

If it still increase by 2 it means there is something in solrx_scripts.php or before it.